# Open Excel Woorkbook with Java

Tags: java, excel

I made a simple version of the main Problem i had with initializing a Workbook with a curtain File Path String. It just has to lead to an Excel File. But when i Debug it Pops many Exceptions although all library s like Apache POI and Commons IO are given in the Project because they are required in the first place to even start it.

I used a Main where i´d call the WorkbookTest class.

Code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new WorkbookTest();
    }
}

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WorkbookTest {
    String sourceFilePath = "C:\\Users\\KRD1PAS\\Desktop\\Ausgabe bestückt.xls";
    String targetFilePath = "C:\\Users\\KRD1PAS\\Desktop\\Import.xls";

    Workbook targetWorkbook;
    Workbook sourceWorkbook;



    {
        try {
            sourceWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(sourceFilePath));
            targetWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(targetFilePath));

            Sheet sourceWorksheet = sourceWorkbook.getSheet("Ausgabeliste");
            Sheet targetWorksheet = targetWorkbook.getSheet("Ersatzteilliste Gesamt");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to initialize the Workbook, but like i said many Exceptions would Pop up for some reason, the exceptions are listed underneath.

Exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
    at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.<clinit>(IOUtils.java:43)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FileMagic.valueOf(FileMagic.java:209)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:222)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:185)
    at WorkbookTest.<init>(WorkbookTest.java:19)
    at Main.main(Main.java:3)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: You haven’t provided log4j. I suggest you use maven to manage your dependencies.

Comment: Move your import statements to the top of your file (under your package statement, if you have one). Java files have structure -- you can't just randomly jumble statements together and expect good results.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I'd expect those are two different files (because two public classes), the OP just put them together in one code block.

Answer (score 0):

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager` means that Apache POI requires another dependency, Log4j. You need to provide that jar.

To make managing dependencies easy, you should use Gradle or (if you must) Maven.